# dependencies should not point at files within the project directory

Tags: java, maven

I looked up the issue before hand and seen others with similar problems but none of the solutions worked for me.

I am a complete noob with Maven but I just imported a project from GitHub. Now I am having problems with getting the dependencies to work. When I clean it gives me the following errors.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further         details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.walrusone.skywars:skywarsreloadedplugin-api:jar:API
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.bukkit:bukkit:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/bukkit-1.8.6-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 19, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.walrusone.skywars:skywarsreloadedplugin-v1_7_R3:jar:v1_7_R3
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.bukkit:craftbukkit:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 19, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.walrusone.skywars:skywarsreloadedplugin-v1_7_R4:jar:v1_7_R4
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.bukkit:craftbukkit:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/craftbukkit-1.7.10-R0.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 19, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.walrusone.skywars:skywarsreloadedplugin-v1_8_R1:jar:v1_8_R1
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.bukkit:craftbukkit:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/craftbukkit-1.8.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 19, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.walrusone.skywars:skywarsreloadedplugin-v1_8_R2:jar:v1_8_R2
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.bukkit:craftbukkit:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/craftbukkit-1.8.3.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 19, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.walrusone.skywars:skywarsreloadedplugin-v1_8_R3:jar:v1_8_R3
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.bukkit:craftbukkit:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/craftbukkit-1.8.4.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 19, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.walrusone.skywars:SkyWarsReloadedPlugin:jar:V2.8
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.bukkit:bukkit:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/craftbukkit-1.8.4.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 72, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

I believe this is different from the original error which was telling me it could not find it, so I went ahead and downloaded all .jar files and put it in the correct places. Now I have no clue what to do.

The other problem I have is whenever I try to edit or add a class it doesn't act like a regular jar file. I cant do like Main.instance.stacticMethod() when I type Main. it just sits there.

If you need any additional files, please let me know.

Also if anyone knows any good tutorial videos on maven

Comment: These are not errors, they are warnings and do not fail the build. Since you are building a project you imported from a 3rd party, you can safely ignore them (or tell the 3rd party that their Maven build got some warnings _they_ should not ignore).

Comment: Being a self-declared _"noob",_ have you considered to start at the [Maven Users Centre](https://maven.apache.org/users/index.html) with its _5 minutes_ and _Getting Started_ tutorials?

Comment: @Tunaki I think the original dev didn't setup maven right. https://github.com/walrusone/SkyWarsReloaded

Comment: @GeroldBroser I'll check that out, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 12):

The point of maven is that you *should* not have to download the dependencies. Just clone the project. You should see a file `pom.xml` in the root directory. Then enter

```
mvn compile
```

This should compile the software and download the dependencies in the progress. The dependencies are not stored in the project folder, they are put in `~/.m2/...` using the default config.

Edit: The warnings seem to be a problem caused by the maintainers of the project not understanding maven correctly. They seem to have added jars to the project instead of dependencies.

Next edit: Consider for example the file `pom.xml` in the `v1_8_R3` module: it links to jars in the base directory:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
  <artifactId>craftbukkit</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/craftbukkit-1.8.4.jar</systemPath>
  <type>jar</type>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

using system paths is generally discouraged. The *correct* way would have been for the devs to ship the jar as a separate artifact. See [this question and the related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project)

Comment: It is actually `.m2`, not `.m2e` :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also thought this, cause thats what I heard was Maven was to make it so I didn't have to find the dependencies. Here's the Github so that you can confirm. https://github.com/walrusone/SkyWarsReloaded

Comment: While you are hoping not to install any libraries, you MAY have to due to availability. This happened to me with Spring, Lombok and Java 10. Still looking for a solution to this problem...

Comment: Why Maven do not support. Every organization doesn't have a private Maven Library

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was to use `${pom.basedir}` instead of `${project.basedir}`.  Though `pom.*` is deprecated with Maven 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need add this plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```